# Get data row from Access MDB and show in text box

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ms-access

I have a access database(mdb). Which has columns ID, Name, Email ID. I have textbox to show the results lets say ID_textbox, Name_textbox, EmaiId_textbox. I have a text box and a button called find.

What I want is when I enter a value in textbox and click find button. It should search for the value in ID column and get the results of name and email of that row and show it in there textbox.

Your help will be appreciated. Thanks

I have googled it this is not a duplicate question. I can't find answer in google so I made a question. Plzz help me out.

I tried some code

```
public void fff(string recno)
{

    myconn.ConnectionString = connestr;
    OleDbDataAdapter adap = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    dtcmd.Connection = myconn;
    dtcmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM sample WHERE [id] = '" + recno + "'";
    myconn.Open();
    var dr = dtcmd.ExecuteReader();
    dr.Read();
    email_tb.Text = dr.GetString(2);
    dr.Close();
    dtcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    myconn.Close();
}
```

I found the issue. The above is public function and isn't changing tb value. How to fix it

Comment: Other than the SQL Injection vulnerability and improper disposal of resources, this code looks ok. What is it doing? Does it error?

Comment: It doesn't show the text in textbox. Nothing happens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        dtcmd.Connection = myconn;
        dtcmd.CommandText = "SELECT Name, EmailId FROM sample WHERE [id] = '" + find_tb.Text + "'";
        if (myconn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            myconn.Open();
        }
        OleDbDataReader dr = dtcmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                email_tb.Text = dr["EmailId"].ToString();
            }
        }
        dr.Close();
        myconn.Close();
```

Comment: No use while is also not working. But if I use this cmd `dtcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` in the bottom it is showing error. `An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.`

Comment: If (dr.Read()) is a shortcut for if (dr.HasRows) { if (dr.Read() {}}

Comment: If you use `while (dr.Read()) { email_tb.Text = dr["EmailId"].ToString(); }` then if you have 10 records, you will see result of last record in your `TextBox`.

Comment: Also avoid writing queries this way. Use parametrized queries to prevent SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Off-topic but as I said in another post, don't post code-only answers. Probably you are not a native English speaker, but don't worry. Most people here are not native English speakers. It's enough to add some simple description to your question to show other users why your answer may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Change your IF Statement to While, it will work

```
while (dr.Read())
    {
        email_tb.Text = dr.GetString(0);
    }
```

Comment: if (expression) and while(expression). Why would you think that if you convert an if() into while() it would work? Why should if (false) be different than while(false)? Or if(true) be different from while(true) when the while loop should be executed only once?

Comment: Yes, If only once to execute, then no difference.

Answer (score -1):

Internet is full of answers to this question and also tons of starter videos show how that is done. Anyway, you might use IQToolkit from codeplex and Linq, thus it would be easier to code:

```
var data = db.TableName.SingleOrDefault( r => r.ID == ID_textbox );
if (data != null)
{
  Name_textbox.Text = data.Name;
  EmaiId_textbox.Text = data.Email;
}
```

This is only one of many ways.

EDIT: This is based on your added later sample code:

```
string path=@"c:\myFolder\MyDb.mdb";
using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+path))
{
   var cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT Name, EmailId 
    FROM sample 
    WHERE [id] = @id"; 
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", find_tb.Text.Trim());
   con.Open();
   OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   if (dr.Read())
   {
      email_tb.Text = (string)dr["EmailId"];
   }
   con.Close();
}
```

You are searching on a string value and its trailing spaces might affect the result, as well as the casing. If it is not finding anything:

1. Be sure it is not casing problem.
2. Be sure that you are looking into correct mdb file (access is file based, and in a project the file you are looking into might not be the one you think unless you are using a fullpath and filename).

Comment: Sorry mate I didn't understood the answer what is db is it datatable or dataset. I have a datatable(dt) defined.

Comment: Hey thx for you replay.. I found the issue... I'm using it in a public void function. It is not changing the text of the tb. How to fix it. I can't make it private because I'm calling this function from another form

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. If you mean the place where you used doesn't have access to UI, use that method just to return the row data.